# invalid token '}' in class struct or interface member declaration when line19 [MaxLength(2048)] is added

Tags: c#

```
using System; 
using System.Collections.Generic; 
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations; 
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema; 
using System.Linq; 
using System.Web;

namespace Memberships.Entities 
{
    [Table("Item")]
    public class Item
    {
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [MaxLenght(255)]
        [Required]

        public string Title { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(2048)]

    } 
}
```

Comment: Don´t post images of code, instead copy the code to the question.

Comment: attributes decorate properties.  you can't have an attribute at the bottom on a class declaration.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you put an attribute to, well, nothing. Attributes go before their target:

```
using System; 
using System.Collections.Generic; 
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations; 
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema; 
using System.Linq; 
using System.Web;

namespace Memberships.Entities 
{
    [Table("Item")]
    public class Item
    {
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        [MaxLenght(255)]
        [Required]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(2048)]
        public string Title { get; set; }    
    } 
}
```

By the way, setting `MaxLenght` of a PK and marking it as required makes no sense.

Comment: Also setting the MaxLenght of an PK also makes no sense.

Comment: @Fran That's what I said :)

Comment: I just refreshed.  that wasn't your original post ;)

Comment: Both the generation and validity checking of the Primary Keys should be left to the Database. Putting this kind of check into the Clients is just askign for race conditions and other problems. If you need the value of a autogenerated column of a row that you just inserted, the INSERT OUTPUT Syntax is the way to go.

Comment: @Christopher Not sure what you are talking about, `DatabaseGeneratedAttribute` is for letting Entity Framework know that you won't supply a value and instead the database will set it

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto: It the Database will provide it, you should be permissive. Do not use any atributes that limit values (like MaxLenght) in that case. You only run into issues like the DB value range changing and your application suddenly having issues (hopefully crashes) because you truncated the values. At worst it might silently truncate and then you will have realy issues.

Comment: @Christopher That's why I mentioned that it makes no sense